# How can I get an item from UIAlertViewController for XCTest?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I added the accessibility key like this:

```
alertController.view.accessibilityIdentifier = "alertViewController"
```

And when I try:

`app.otherElements["alertViewController"]`

It does not work. How can I get also an action that is inside the alertController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert controller as a whole is not an accessibility element. You will need to search for buttons (rather than other elements) and use the localised text rather than an identifier as you do not have access to set the identifier of the alert controller's subviews.